# layout with twitter-bootstrap form

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have difficulties to arrange the css bootstrap form .
On top of the picture below is the layout I get and just under is the layout I would like to obtain:
http://s27.postimg.org/dfztgn35v/flow_Root3665.png
This is: the first column witn names aligned on their last letter, and aligned input fields on the left and on the right.

Here is the css I used:

```
<div class="well">

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Event</legend>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="input-append date" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Date</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="input-group input-append date" id="startDatePicker">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="datepicker"  id="datepicker1" readonly style="background-color: white" /><span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input-append type" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Type</label>
      <div class="col-lg-2">
      <select class="form-control" id="select">
        <option>select1</option>
        <option>select2</option>
      </select>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputTitle" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Title</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input kl_virtual_keyboard_secure_input="on" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" placeholder="Title" type="text" maxlength="30">
        </div>
      </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="textArea" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Description</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="textArea" placeholder="Description" maxlength="200"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

 </div>
 </fieldset>
 </form>

 </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't added your `css` code yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some minor CSS you can acheive that. See example.

```css
#soForm input,
#soForm select {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 4px solid #444;
}
#soForm textarea {
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 4px solid #444;
}
#soForm .input-group-addon {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 13px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-right: 4px solid #444;
  border-top: 4px solid #444;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #444;
}
.btn.btn-submit {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 4px solid #444;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #soForm .soForm {
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  #soForm .control-label {
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="well">
  <div class="container">
    <form id="soForm" name="soForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="date" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div class="input-group soForm">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="type" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <select class="form-control soForm" id="type">
            <option>select1</option>
            <option>select2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <textarea class="form-control soForm" rows="5" id="desc"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is nearly perfect. But the <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span> from the datepicker input messes evrything up. On top of the picture is what I get  now. On the bottom is what it was before your code but with the alignement problems. http://s28.postimg.org/re1vvy2nh/Sans_titre_1.png. So I dont know how to deal with the glyphicon.

Comment: See my updated code. Please don't forget to mark your question as answered if the solution works for you.

Comment: Tank you so much for your help. It completely solved the problem.